# how to find the area of circle in javascript by the given radius

Tags: javascript, area

**Write a function area that calculates the area of a circle. The function is given the radius of the circle.
**

my code is this

```
let r;
    let radius=r*r;
    function area(r){
    return (Math.PI.radius);
    }
```

Error is showing that "area(0) does not return 0, but undefined." please explain this code.

I am new to this world please don't mind if you think this is one of the simple questions I have no one to ask except you guys!

Answer (score 0):

`Math.PI` does not have a radius - it is a mathematical constant, which you have to multiply with the squared radius of the circle. Also you did not assign any value to `r` - so it is `undefined`. This one works:

```js
function area(r) {
  return Math.PI * r ** 2; /* r ** 2 is the JS notation of potenatiating a number */
}

console.log(area(0));
console.log(area(1));
console.log(area(5));
console.log(area(10));
```

Comment: I was only writing function for practice onm online console that's why I didn't define r.

Comment: @Satyam_M well, if you don't define a variable it will be `undefined`, so you don't have to wonder about an error / `undefined` result ! ;)